# I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram-api

I want to display a instagram hashtag stream of photos on my app. But when I choose I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website to submit for review it says This use case is not supported. So how to achieve if I want to show pictures of a specific hashtag?
Right now I haven't implemented any of the code in my project regarding this. But I've downloaded [this library](https://github.com/daj007/InstagramProject) and I changed it's `client_id` to test. If it works successfully I'll implement it in my project.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post some code so we can figure out the problem.

Comment: @Pilatus check now.

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is old and does not support the Instagram API changes of June 1, 2016.

The library is still using `client_id` to make API calls which is no longer supported, you need a valid `access_token` to make API calls.